# Bad calling of QList::push_back()

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, qlist

I'm trying to insert a `QList` in another `QList`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
parser.y:40: error: no matching function for call to 'QList<QList<QString> >::insert(QList<QList<QString> >&)'
```

Trying to push a `QList` called partialFormula into another QList called formula:

```
formula.push_back(partialFormula);
```

I think my error is in the definition of my QList templates, because the expected value of the formula `QList` is a `QList` of `QString`, but I'm trying to insert a `QList` of `QList` of `QString`.

```
QList<QList<QString> > formula;
QList<QList<QString> > partialFormula;
formula.push_back(partialFormula); //error.
```

Also, I want to insert in partialFormula another QList >, and so on..., Do I have to create a `class` or a `struct`?

What can I do to do this?

My code:

```
#include <QList>
#include <QString>

int main () {
    QList<QList<QString> > formula;
    QList<QList<QString> > partialFormula;
    QList<QString> atomicCondition;

    //It works!
    partialFormula.push_back(atomicCondition);
    //It does not work.
    formula.push_back(partialFormula);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, but your `formula` list expects `QList<QString>` as an element, but you insert `QList<QList<QString> >` instead. I think the error is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push_back` function is only there for STL-compatibility reasons and accepts only appending of variables of type `T` in your case `QString`. Have a look here: [QT Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#push_back)

Try using one of the following:

```
formula.append(partialFormula);
```

or

```
formula += partialFormula;
```

or

```
formula << partialFormula;
```

or

```
formula.insert(formula.size(), partialFormula);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append another `QList` of the same type, you can use the [+= operator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#operator-2b-eq):

```
formula += partialFormula;
```